# repo.maven.apache.org not working?

Tags: java, maven

***BIG EDIT**: The problem is "solved". Some wise guy from our company decided that our office should start accessing internet via proxy without notifying anyone.*

The maven builds stopped working for all my java projects today. It always hangs on this problem:

```
Could not transfer artifact [some artifact] from/to central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Checksum validation failed, 
expected  but is 63801e851fe885601a0bd0eceb6501f7db37e47e
```

On different projects it hangs on different libraries, but the expected checksum is always the same. I think it's not a problem of my configuration, because it started happening for the other guys here.

The repository seems ok as I can download the artifacts manually.

EDIT: I'm doing build on clean local repository.

EDIT2: Repository is defined in the main pom like this:

```
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>Maven Central</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      </repository>
    <repositories>
```

EDIT3: It looks like the maven always retrieves this from the artifactory(in hex, because there are no visible characters)

```
0000000: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
0000010: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
0000020: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
0000030: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
0000040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
0000050: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020                  
0000060: 2020 200a
```

Comment: Did you remove the expected checksum or is it really empty?

Comment: I'm doing ```rm -R ~/.m2/repository``` before each build to be sure.
Oh... I didn't remove anything. The checksum is empty

Comment: If that URL is for Maven Central, it's not the default URL I'm familiar with.  I'd recommend trying http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ instead to see if that makes any difference

Comment: Which artifact has that problem? Always the same artifact? [The US official is](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 the other in europe is http://uk.maven.org/maven2 Have you problems with network ?

Comment: It's for all artifacts downloaded from that respository. Sometimes it fails on org.apache.maven.shared:file-management, sometime on maven-plexus.

Comment: Are you using a repository manager ? Which version of the artifacts?

Comment: I'm not sure what is repository manager. I've got repository defined in the main pom(see edit of original post).

Comment: Do you have caching problems with your companies proxy server as your said your colleagues have the same problem?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no proxy server in our company. But I started getting another exception: ```error: error reading /home/user/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar; error in opening zip file
```

Comment: What networking devices do you have between you and the outside world? Have any of them changed?

Comment: Dave: Do you think it can be some firewall issue? I'm not aware of any network changes, but I'm in big company so anything is possible.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj about the zip file error: do you have concurrent access to that file by more than one maven process?

Comment: What's in your `settings.xml`? You shouldn't need to explicitly define the central repo like that in your POM.

Comment: h3nrik: The file is always the same with the same checksum(some nonprinting characters). It is not a valid jar.

Tom G: In settings.xml, there are only passwords for internal artifactories. We need to have it like this because of builds on jenkins. But I doubt it's an issue, because it's like this for a long time.